# How to parameterize tests for each iteration in Postman collection?

Tags: api, postman, web-api-testing, newman, postman-collection-runner

My GET request goes like this:

```
<some ip>/search?IW_INDEX={IW_INDEX}&IW_FIELD_WEB_STYLE={IW_FIELD_TEXT}
```

The data file is as follows:

```
IW_INDEX,IW_FIELD_TEXT
index1,text1
index2,text2
```

My test for iteration 1 is as follows:

```
tests["parameter1"] = responseBody.has("value=\"19\"");
```

Now this value 19 will change depending upon the iteration and might be 20 in iteration 2.

Is there a way to provide expected test results iteration-wise in Postman?

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do it by adding a column to your CSV file with "expected_result" and in the test, call that value by {{data.expected_result}}, so your test should probably look like:

`tests["parameter1"] = responseBody.has("value=\"{{data.expected_result}}\");`